# JQuery slider breaks on second click of thumbnail

Tags: jquery

I have an ongoing problem with a video slider panel (using stacked iframes and z-index), which breaks when a thumbnail is clicked the second time.  I have searched high and low for a solution but am stuck; everything I've tried has not worked.

The live website is http://www.nishasamuel.com.  When you click on a thumbnail, you are scrolled to the top of the page and the new video fades in over the top, using z-index. That's fine, but if you click on the currently selected thumbnail a second time it breaks in the main panel at the top.

So the best idea I've come up with, but am struggling to implement correctly, is to flag the thumbnail with a 'current' class as soon as it's been clicked. Then if it's clicked again an if statement in the JQuery function can prevent the function from running again, thus circumventing the problem. But how to do this? I think I'm close with the lines that are commented out below but I'm not quite there, struggling with how reactivate the click functionality on the selected thumbnail when another one is cliked. It's likely to simply be my lack of JQuery expertise. I really have tried :-/

Here's the JQuery code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function selectWsImage(controlElement, fadeSpeed) { // find this thumbnail's image and display it in the content panel
        var targetId = controlElement.attr('data-toggle');
        var $selectedItem = $('#video_gallery_panel li.selected');
        var $targetItem = $(targetId);
            //if (!$targetItem.hasClass('current')) {
                //$targetItem.removeClass('current');
                $selectedItem.removeClass('selected').css('z-index', 2);
                $targetItem.addClass('selected').hide().css('z-index', 3).fadeIn(fadeSpeed, function() {
                    $selectedItem.css('z-index', 1);
                    });
                //$targetItem.addClass('current');
            //}
        }
        wsGalleryFadeInterval = 1000;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#homepage_top_right_panel a').click( function(event) {
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "180px" });
                event.preventDefault();
                selectWsImage($(this), wsGalleryFadeInterval);
            });
        })
</script>
```

...and the relevant excerpt of the HTML (feel free to check the source at the above link if needed):

```
<ul id="video_gallery_panel">

                <li id="video_feature_post1" class="selected">
                    <div id="video_panel">
                        <div id="video_panel_text">
                            <h5 id="heading1" class="motion_graphics">Motion Graphics</h5>
                            <h3 id="heading2">Motion Graphics Showreel</h3>
                            <p id="paragraph">Highlights of exciting motion graphics projects and animation work I have been involved in.</p>
                        </div>
                        <iframe id="player" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/43499006?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=42a1b2" width="720" height="405" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen style="position:absolute; margin-top:-400px;"></iframe>
                    </div><!-- end video_panel -->
                </li>

                <li id="video_feature_post2">
                    <div id="video_panel">
                        <div id="video_panel_text">
                            <h5 id="heading1" class="vfx">VFX</h5>
                            <h3 id="heading2">St. Mungo&#8217;s TV Advert</h3>
                            <p id="paragraph">St. Mungo&#039;s Christmas TV Ad &quot;When You&#039;ve Lost Everything&quot;</p>
                        </div>
                        <iframe id="player" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/81405012?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ff4a61" width="720" height="405" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen style="position:absolute; margin-top:-400px;"></iframe>
                    </div><!-- end video_panel -->
                </li>

                <li id="video_feature_post3">
                    <div id="video_panel">
                        <div id="video_panel_text">
                            <h5 id="heading1" class="motion_graphics">Motion Graphics</h5>
                            <h3 id="heading2">Doctor Care Anywhere</h3>
                            <p id="paragraph">A video animation for a new online medical service. I received this video from my client which I had to revise the characters in the animation and create and replace a section seamlessly to make the animation more relevant to their business.  </p>
                        </div>
                        <iframe id="player" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/78800579?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=42a1b2" width="720" height="405" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen style="position:absolute; margin-top:-400px;"></iframe>
                    </div><!-- end video_panel -->
                </li>

            </ul>

            <div class="clear"></div>

                    <div id="homepage_top_right_panel" class="selected">
                        <h5 class="motion_graphics">Motion Graphics</h5>
                        <h4>Motion Graphics Showreel</h4>
                        <div id="bg_motion_graphics">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="#video_feature_post1"><img width="220" height="124" src="http://www.nishasamuel.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/motion-graphics-showreel.jpg" alt="Motion Graphics Showreel" title="Motion Graphics Showreel video sample" class="motion_graphics" /></a>
                        </div><!-- end homepage_top_right_panel -->
                    </div>

                    <div id="homepage_top_right_panel">
                        <h5 class="vfx">VFX</h5>
                        <h4>St. Mungo&#8217;s TV Advert</h4>
                        <div id="bg_vfx">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="#video_feature_post2"><img width="220" height="124" src="http://www.nishasamuel.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/mungoes.jpg" alt="St. Mungo&#8217;s TV Advert" title="St. Mungo&#8217;s TV Advert video sample" class="vfx" /></a>
                        </div><!-- end homepage_top_right_panel -->
                    </div>

                    <div id="homepage_top_right_panel">
                        <h5 class="motion_graphics">Motion Graphics</h5>
                        <h4>Doctor Care Anywhere</h4>
                        <div id="bg_motion_graphics">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="#video_feature_post3"><img width="220" height="124" src="http://www.nishasamuel.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/dca.jpg" alt="Doctor Care Anywhere" title="Doctor Care Anywhere video sample" class="motion_graphics" /></a>
                        </div><!-- end homepage_top_right_panel -->
                    </div>
```

Hoping someone can help - I know there are lots of JQuery experts out there :-)

Thanks

Comment: One issue is that the `selected` class never gets removed from the previously selected element. No matter which thumbnail you click, the first element always has the `selected` class. Not sure if fixing that will resolve your issue, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks. So this is part of the problem too then! I'm open to all suggestions and code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, finally. It simply took a well-placed 'if not...' check that the current thumbnail wasn't already selected (ie had the 'selected' class) before running the function's z-index switching:

```
if (!$targetItem.hasClass('selected')) {...}
```

The full function is now:

```
    function selectWsImage(controlElement, fadeSpeed) { // find this thumbnail's image and display it in the content panel
        var targetId = controlElement.attr('data-toggle');
        var $selectedItem = $('#video_gallery_panel li.selected');
        var $targetItem = $(targetId);
            if (!$targetItem.hasClass('selected')) {
                $selectedItem.removeClass('selected').css('z-index', 2);
                $targetItem.addClass('selected').hide().css('z-index', 3).fadeIn(fadeSpeed, function() {
                    $selectedItem.css('z-index', 1);
                    });
            }
        }
        wsGalleryFadeInterval = 1000;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#homepage_top_right_panel a').click( function(event) {
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "180px" });
                event.preventDefault();
                selectWsImage($(this), wsGalleryFadeInterval);
            });
        })
```

Hope this saves someone with the same issue a few headaches in the future.